# Is a function allowed?

Tags: discussion

Is it allowed to use a function instead of a complete program, in a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) question?

(This has probably been asked before, I'm unable to locate the link.)

Asked wrt @agtoever 's query on [Output the qwerty keyboard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64639/output-the-qwerty-keyboard)

Comment: In short: yes, unless the author of the challenge (you in this case), overrules the default. Furthermore, [even unnamed functions are allowed](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/should-function-literals-be-allowed-when-a-function-is-asked-for/1503#1503) by default. However, snippets/REPL code is not.